# JavaScript unit tests with Jasmine and RequireJS

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, requirejs, jasmine

In my visual studio I have two projects one of them provide functionality for SharePoint page and another one for testing purposes.

In the first project I have few view modules that use RequireJS as a dependency injector.

I need to write js tests in another project:

```
    /// <reference path="Scripts/require.js" />

describe('directly', function () {
   beforeEach(function() {
    require.config({
        baseUrl: '../CopmanyName/Layouts/1033/Scripts/CopmanyName/ProjectName/app',

    });
});

    it('should see booking', function (done) {

        require(['Booking'],
            function (booking) {
                expect(booking).toBeDefined();
                done();
            });
    });

});
```

The test failed. It appears that requireJS is not able find the Booking module, which is defined like that:

```
define(['knockout','moment'], function(ko, moment) {
return function Booking(data) {// some functionality}
```

The error message is: "Expected undefined to be defined." in expect(booking).toBeDefined();

Comment: What precise error message do you get? If you look at the network requests, what requests related to module loading are working, and which are failing?

Comment: The error message is: "Expected undefined to be defined." in  expect(booking).toBeDefined();

Comment: Ok, this information should be in the body of your question, not in a comment. But this also tells me that your statement "It appears that requireJS is not able find the Booking module" is not correct. If RequireJS did not find the module, then the code in the callback you pass to require would not execute at all. So RequireJS loads something. There's another problem.